# How to make datagrid selection and hover effect (blue color) programmatically

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, selection

I have two datagrids which should do everything synchronic except the data entry. I already managed to make them scroll synchronic by using the scroll event. My question is now how to select a item of a datagrid only programmatically, and how to get the mouseover effect and underlining the corresponding row with a bright blue color?

any hints will be appreciated!
Markus

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: the change event lets you mark wether someone clicked a item in the datagrid:

```
change="changeSecondGrid(event)"/>    
change="changeFirstGrid(event)"/>
```

and then you can use this method to simulate the same action in the other dataGrid:

```
firstGrid.editedItemPosition = { columnIndex: event.columnIndex, rowIndex: event.rowIndex };
```

Markus